# SendBird Android SDK - delete member from group channel

Tags: android, chat, sendbird

I have integrated SendBird ([Official site](https://sendbird.com/)) Chat SDK in my android application. They do not have the feature to remove a member from Group Channel but we want it because it is an essential feature. I have used their metadata approach like this: 
If a member is removed, put its userid in "deletedUserIds" key. Put a condition everywhere in the app that if his userid is contained in that ids then do this otherwise do this.

#### Questions :

1. is there any better approach than this, because it is very buggy to put conditions everywhere.
2. can we load metadata information with group channel information or filter group channels based on above condition. Ex. if User "A" has been removed from Group "G" and logged in user is "A", when he tries to load groups list, only those groups should come which do not have "A" userid in metadata "deletedUserIds" key.

Comment: Hi Harish, did you find any solution for this? Please let me know.

Comment: Not found yet....